# Android market subscription like Apple iTunes. Is it possible?

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to take money from client in android without asking the client any credit card? For example if client is subscribed to google with his credit card and he downloads the free app. In this free app, he wants some extra service and this service costs 1$.

If he press ok to this service is it possible that he directly pay to android market, and app. owner get this money?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is you should use the in app billing API : http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Also please note that it's quite a delicate question to sell things that you don't own..